# Does mongo session have id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I want to specified what session is running to handle only that session.
Ex:

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
const sessionId = session.id.id.toString('hex');

// use sessionId as memcache key

memcache.set(sessionId, { data: sessionId })

// do something here
const data = memcache.get(sessionId);
// do something with data

memcache.del(sessionId);
```

Current, sessionId is only one value, it's never change (I don't know why)
If have 2 request at the same time, 2 process run parallel. I need to sessionId to can get or delete data in memcache truly.

Comment: It does, and it is  generated on the client when session is acquired, so I doubt 2 processes can have the same session id. Why do you need it anyway? You can't reuse it, or get a session by id. What are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlexBlex When I start nodejs app, I connect to mongo as well. So all session I created have a same id. but when I restart nodejs app and reconnect to mongo, session is changed. I need sessionId for each request is difference because I need storage some data while nodejs processing, after done I will clear cache. The session is used in all process for transaction, so I want to use session as a thing to specify request instead of generate a random id and pass they to all processing functions

Comment: _so I want to use session as a thing to specify request instead of generate a random id_ Any specific reason for that? The session id **is a random id** :https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/main/src/sessions.ts#L829 no better than the one you can generate yourself. Having special purpose in transactions and retryable writes, it's less ideal to use on application level. Leave it to the driver. The best thing you can do with it is to log it for debugging purposes if there are any issues with multi-document transactions or causal consistency.